# How to add item when using List (Of)?

Tags: vb.net

I created a class where i declared some properties.

```
Public Class BlogPost

    Dim _postTitleUrl As String = String.Empty
    Dim _pageGUID As String = String.Empty


    Property postTitleUrl() As String
        Get
            Return _postTitleUrl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _postTitleUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property pageGUID() As String
        Get
            Return _pageGUID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _pageGUID = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, I have another class where I want to set the values.

```
Public Class SetBlogData

  Public blogPostList As New List(Of BlogPost)
  Public dataCounter as integer = 0

  blogPostList(dataCounter).pageGUID = mainBlogSPWeb.ID.ToString
```

....

This gives me an error about Index was out of range. Hpw can I properly access the properties in BlogPost class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because your list has nothing .

You should use add method to add your new item. Like ...

```
        Dim blogPostList = New List(Of BlogPost)
        Dim blogPost = New BlogPost
        blogPost.pageGUID = mainBlogSPWeb.ID.ToString
        blogPostList.Add(blogPost)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a `BlogPost` in your list by writing `blogPost.List.Add(New BlogPost())`

Comment: Where will I include blogPost.List.Add(New BlogPost())?

Answer (score 1):

I find this a good way of inserting into a list:

1) Check if the list is nothing

2) If so instantiate a new list

3) Add the value to list.

Below is an example.

```
Private Sub ExampleAddValueToList(ByVal value as BlogPost)
    Try
        If _blogPostList Is Nothing Then
            _blogPostList = New List(Of BlogPost)
        End If

        _blogPostList.Add(value)

    Catch ex As Exception
       debug.write(ex.message)
    End Try
End Sub
```